# Git: checkout vs restore single file

Tags: git

I'll preface this by mentioning that I've been working with Git for years, but my knowledge is limited to very basic workflows. Realizing this, I've been getting a lot better with "advanced" Git features, but here's a question I can't quite figure out:

What exactly does `git checkout [file]` do?

My understanding was that it retrieves the latest revision/commit of that specific file, discarding any unstaged working copy.

So, I am wondering if this differs in any way from `git restore [file]`, and when I might want to use either of the two.

Sadly, I haven't been able to find a super clear answer elsewhere.

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58003889/83605

Comment: @Aziz Great note... that helps me understand the context behind restore a little bit better. So they basically achieve the exact same thing, but restore was included as a variant (among others) to reduce common confusion?

Comment: @Andys1814 Basically. I could imagine that once the interface provided by `git restore` stabilizes, `git checkout` can be changed to no longer duplicate what has been delegated to `git restore`.

Comment: Fort Party of the history see https://stackoverflow.com/q/57123031/5784831. Especially vonc s answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Between the answers from [axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62703212/1256452) and [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62702722/1256452) you have a pretty complete picture, but I'd like to cover the whole thing a bit differently.  There are two `git checkout` forms of interest here:

1. `git checkout -- path`: the *`path`* argument is treated as a file or directory—if it's a directory, it means all files within that directory, recursively—and Git copies the *current copy of the file as found in the index* out to your work-tree.

   We'll say more about the index in a moment.
2. `git checkout HEAD -- path`: the *`path`* argument is treated the same way, but Git copies the *current copy of the file as found in the `HEAD` commit* to *both* the index *and* your work-tree.

   You can use a name other than `HEAD` here: any commit specifier works, and Git copies *that commit*'s copy of the file to both the index and your work-tree.

For `git restore`, you have more flexibility.  You can tell Git to copy a file:

- from the index, or from any commit (use the `--source` option to choose a source explicitly, or let the command figure one out on its own)
- to the index, or to your work-tree, or both (use the `--staged` option to copy to the index, and/or the `--worktree` option to copy to the work-tree).

Note that if you use `git checkout` and choose a commit, the file goes to both places: the index, and your work-tree.  Copying "from the index, to the index" does not really do anything (and might net you a complaint since it seems like a weird thing to ask).

#### About the index and your work-tree

Your work-tree is pretty simple and obvious.  Git stores each commit as a full snapshot: a complete copy of *every* file you've committed.  But, files stored inside Git's commits are stored in a special, read-only, compressed, de-duplicated, Git-only format.  This keeps the `.git` directory (the repository proper) from getting too big too fast.  Most commits really just re-use most previous files, which means the de-duplication works extremely well.  For those times when it doesn't work so well, the compression usually takes care of the rest.<sup>1</sup>  On the other hand, because the files here *are* read-only and aren't ordinary files, you can't actually *use* them to get your work done.  Git has to copy these files out, turning then back into ordinary files that you, and your computer, can use.

The useful, everyday-work copies of your files appear in what Git calls your *work-tree* or *working tree*.  You can do anything you want with these files.  Git doesn't actually *use* them!  It does *create* them, having extracted the compressed Git-only stored files from a commit, but it doesn't make commits *from* them.

Git's *index*, which Git also calls the *staging area* or sometimes—rarely these days—the *cache*, holds a copy<sup>2</sup> of every file that came out of the *current* commit and is now ready to go into the *next* commit you will make.<sup>3</sup>  When you run `git commit`, Git just packages up whatever is in the index at that time.  This is why you keep having to `git add` a file.  If you change a file, you haven't changed *Git's copy* of the file: you have only changed the work-tree copy.  You use `git add` to tell Git: *Copy my updated work-tree file back into your index, replacing the old copy there.*

Hence, the index always holds your *proposed next commit*.  You use `git add`, or if you need to remove files, `git rm`, to update—or remove—these index copies of your files.  They start out with the copies from the commit you've checked out: the current or `HEAD` commit.  So if you *haven't* used `git add`, the index and `HEAD` commit copies normally match.<sup>4</sup>  When they do match, the presence of the index copy tends to be invisible: `git status` doesn't mention the index copy, for instance.

If you're curious, though, try running `git ls-files --stage` (be prepared for a lot of output in a big repository!—this command doesn't run its output through a pager).  This will show you *every* file in the index.

---

<sup>1</sup>The compressed, de-duplicated format doesn't work for some very large binary file formats.  In this case Git can become bloated.  This is where things like Git-LFS come in.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, the index doesn't hold an actual copy of the file, but rather a reference.  The difference only shows up if you start using the low level commands `git update-index` or `git ls-files --stage`, which can inspect the index contents directly.  For everyday use, though, you can just think of the index as holding a copy of the files.  The index copy is in the frozen and de-duplicated format—i.e., pre-frozen and pre-de-duplicated, albeit overwrite-able—which makes committing go fast.

<sup>3</sup>The index also takes on an expanded role when you have to deal with merge conflicts.  This answer does not cover this case.

<sup>4</sup>The word *normally* here is to take care of a lot of corner cases, including things like `git reset --soft` and special varieties of `git commit` that don't necessary use the regular index.

Answer (score 6):

[`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) does two things: it switches branches and it restores files to a certain state.

These two behaviours were extracted in [Git 2.23](https://github.blog/2019-08-16-highlights-from-git-2-23/) in two new commands: [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) and [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore).

`git checkout` still does both things and it will probably keep doing them many years from now but the new commands are recommended because they are more clear.

Answer (score 3):

`git checkout file` will revert the file(s) or folder(s) specified to the index = their **staged** state (or current HEAD if no changes staged for commit).

So let's say your file content on current commit (HEAD) is `a`.

And that you used `git add` in the past to stage a change from content `a` to content `b`.

Then your current `git diff --staged` shows

```
diff --git a/file b/file
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1 +1 @@
-a
+b
```

Additionally further changes were done to the file, but **not** added yet.

Running `git checkout -- file` will revert the file to content `b` and throw away its current content.
Meaning the staged changes (visible in `git diff --staged -- file`) will stay, while unstaged changes (visible in `git diff -- file`) will be lost.

If you want to actually change the file back to HEAD (content `a`), then you'll have to specify that

`git checkout HEAD -- file`

Then both the unstaged and the staged changes will be undone.

(Which you could also do by first unstaging all changes with `git reset -- file` and then doing `git checkout -- file`; or `git reset --hard` to do both at the same time)

---

As to the differences to `git restore` - as that command is tagged `THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. THE BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE.`, it's kinda hard to make any meaningful *prediction* here.

However, based on *current documentation* it apparently also doesn't restore from HEAD by default, but from index (so it will keep the staged changes, just like `git checkout -- file` does)

But I did noticed some interesting difference - `git checkout -- file` will refuse to do anything if the file was deleted (or never existed) in the source. So if you `git rm` a file, then write contents to it - you can't delete it again by using `git checkout -- file`.
`git restore -- file` apparently can be used to "restore" the file to its state of non-existance, i.e. deleting it.