# How to checkout a tag using TortoiseGit in an empty directory on you local PC?

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

My machine is `Windows 7` operating system. The `Git` version is 2.23.windows.1. I have `TortoiseGit` 2.8.0.0 version.

There is a remote repository on `BitBucket`. It has many tags one of them is **v1.5**.

On my local PC there is an empty directory. In it I want to checkout the **v1.5** tag using `TortoiseGit`. How can I do that?

I know how to do it in case of `SVN` as each tag has a different URL so `TortoiseSVN` is pretty easy in such a case but how to do it in `Git` using `TortoiseGit`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/download-a-specific-tag-with-git) answer the question? It doesn't use Tortoise, it's smoother!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download a specific tag with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/download-a-specific-tag-with-git)

Answer (score 0):

From the [TortoiseGit Manual](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-checkout.html), you can open the "Switch/Checkout" dialog by right-clicking on the repository's folder and clicking "Switch/Checkout...", then selecting the "Tag" radio button and selecting your tag (in this case, `v1.5`).

[image: Switch/Checkout Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the source code of a specific version and no further version conrol locally, you can easily download the source code of a tag directly on BitBucket/GitHub/GitLab. For this go to releases and there you will find the download links.

Using TortoiseGit you first have to clone the repository (open the context menu, select "Git Clone" and enter the URL of the repo, cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-clone.html). After that, you have to check out the specific version. For this open the "Switch/Checkout" dialog (from the contextmenu, cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-checkout.html) and select the tag you need.

Technical detail: In Git you cannot check out a tag. You can check out a specific commit, but then it is hard to do further work (this state is called "[detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19033709/3906760)"). It is better to create a branch for a tag and check out this (this is what TortoiseGit does by default unless you uncheck the "Create new branch" checkbox).